# Making imageview invisible causes NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-imageview, invisible

I am running the following code and it gives me NullPointerException in the line iv4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
 Please suggest. Thanks
Code:

```
ImageView iv4;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_score);
            iv4= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
            iv4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

<RelativeLayout 
   xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
   android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent"> 

 <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView4" 
      android:layout_width="110dp" 
      android:layout_height="110dp" 
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
      android:src="@drawable/hg" /> 
  </RelativeLayout>
```

The stack trace is as follows:

```
03-05 03:49:25.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1070): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 03:49:25.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1070): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{bitcream.candyhive.candy/bitcream.candyhive.candy.ScoreActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-05 03:49:25.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-05 03:49:25.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-05 03:49:25.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-05 03:49:25.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-05 03:49:25.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-05 03:49:25.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-05 03:49:25.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-05 03:49:25.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 03:49:25.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-05 03:49:25.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-05 03:49:25.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-05 03:49:25.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 03:49:25.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1070): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-05 03:49:25.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at bitcream.candyhive.candy.ScoreActivity.onCreate(ScoreActivity.java:42)
03-05 03:49:25.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-05 03:49:25.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-05 03:49:25.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     ... 11 more
03-05 03:49:28.297: I/Process(1070): Sending signal. PID: 1070 SIG: 9
```

Comment: post `activity_score.xml`

Comment: the question can seem kind of silly.. do you have declared `R.id.imageView4` inside `activity_score.xml`?

Comment: yes I did so... but still shows the same...!!!

Comment: sure. Could you post the layout?

Comment: Its running in a fresh activity. The layout which produced an error was:
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"> <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/hg" />

    </RelativeLayout>

Comment: @Shubhankar post the activity layout.

Comment: have your tried to clean and rebuild your project?

Answer (score 1):

> NullPointerException in the line iv4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)

Probably there is no `ImageView` with the id `imageView4` in  `activity_score.xml`.

Either you referenced the wrong layout or your layout does not contain the imageview with the id mentioned.

Edit:

Change

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

to

```
<RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

You will get `NullPointerException` if `findViewById` does not find a view with the id mentioned in the current inflated layout.